# Block position, text position and link underlining

Tags: html, css, pagination

I want to add pagination to one of my websites, but I have multiple problems with it, probably due to the fact that I don't have the best CSS skills in the world (they're mediocre at best).

You can see an SSCCE of my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/rmurzea/qE7Ku/3/

1). To make the `margin-bottom` rule work, I had to add it to the `pagination a` class. If I add it directly to the `pagination` class, it doesn't work. Why ?

2). The `content a:hover` property has a `text-decoration: underline` rule. I can't seem to override it in `pagination a:hover`. How can I do it ?

3). I want that block of color and its text on the next line, but specifying a `display: block` rule doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone please help me with these problems ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For 2) how do you want to override it? Do you want no decoration? Use `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: @TylerH I added it but it has no effect.

Comment: I mean, do you want there to be underlining of the links in `content a:hover`? Or not?

Comment: To remove the text-decoration you need to be more specific (`#content .pagination a:hover {  text-decoration: none; }`)

Comment: Right now the only links you have in `content` are the links in `pagination`... so if you don't want them to have `underline`, then why do you have it in `content` in the first place?

Comment: Posting multiple questions in one request leads to only one item getting solved. You should pose multiple requests.

Comment: @TylerH I want some links to be underlined and some not. There are no other links in the example because I only posted a minimal example. So I can't remove the rule from `content`, I need it there. I just want it to be overwritten in some places, like `pagination`.

Comment: For 3) You can add two `<br />` tags before the `<p id="legend">` tag in your HTML. For the links, Paulie_D's fix will work; replace your `.pagination a:hover` entry with his `#content .pagination a:hover` entry.

Comment: @Paulie_D The issues seem to be too small to ask individual questions, especially since they're about the same piece of HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) it works

```
.pagination {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

2) Use !important in your css

```
.pagination a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color: #5D4137;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

3) Replacing your p tag by div should work but it didn't, however I used a div with clear: both and it worked..

Here is your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qE7Ku/4/) updated